# AWS EKS - Create cluster minimum IAM permissions (AccessDenied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Does anyone know what should be the minimum IAM permissions that would allow a user creating an EKS cluster?

I'm assuming a role to just create a cluster with Terraform and that role has got the following statements in its policy defined (nothing more than that):

```
        {
            "Sid": "AllowEKSCreate",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:List*",
                "eks:Describe*",
                "eks:CreateCluster",
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowEKSAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:cluster/my-cluster"
        }
```

In CloudTrail I'am only seeing:

```
AWS access key: XXXXXXXX
AWS region: eu-west-1
Error code: AccessDenied
Event ID: XXXXXXXX
Event name: CreateCluster
Event source: eks.amazonaws.com
```

Successful events:

- sts:GetCallerIdentity
- ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes

No other event is present in CloudTrail that would be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The missing permission was `iam:PassRole` on the Cluster IAM Role resource.

For some reason CloudTrail does not reveal that information :(

P.S.
I think I made my question very clear so am wondering why someone would give me -1.

Comment: Recent announcement from AWS - EKS Service-Linked role:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-eks-supports-service-linked-roles/